# Doubleclick contenteditable element to focus (not as easy at it seems)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, contenteditable

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem for a long time now, so I'm going to ask here now.

Start with a normal contenteditable div element, like this one:

```html
<div contenteditable>Edit this text</div>
```

If you click on the text, you will be able to edit it with the cursor at the position you clicked at.

Now, I don't want the text to be editable on the first click, and I don't want to be able to interact with the text at all while the element is not focused. I could achieve this by disabling the div, turning of contenteditable, with CSS or an overlaying element.

I now want the element to be editable again *on doubleclick* with the exact same behaviour you would expect from clicking the element normally. Let's use JavaScript and a EventListener for `onmousedown` or `ondblclick` for that.

### Example 1

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="editable" contenteditable>Edit this text</div>
</div>
```

```js
overlay.ondblclick = () => {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
    editable.focus();
};

// use onblur to restore the overlay
```

This works, BUT the cursor will be positioned at the start of the element. If you don't use `focus()`, you have to click a third time to focus the element.

### Example 2

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="false">Edit this text</div>
```

```js
editable.ondblclick = () => {
    editable.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
};

// use onblur to set contenteditable to false again
// additional CSS will prevent being able to interact with the text if not focused
```

This works, BUT you will select the word at which you are clicking at instead of putting the text cursor there.

This is for a private project, accessability, compatibility, etc don't matter.

Comment: Perhaps create a functioning snippet with the HTML, CSS and JavaScript to run and clearly state your one objective of "I'm trying to find a solution for this problem" that is not being met by that current code.

Answer (score 0):

After some more hours of research, I came to this solution:

```js
const editable = document.getElementById('editable');

editable.ondblclick = (event) => {
  if (document.activeElement === event.target) return;

  editable.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  selectRange(getMouseEventCaretRange(event));
}

function getMouseEventCaretRange(event) {
    if (event.rangeOffset !== undefined) {
        // The new fancy Firefox-only way that doesn't even have documentation
        let range = document.createRange();

        range.setStart(event.rangeParent, event.rangeOffset);
        range.collapse(true);

        return range;
    } else if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
        // The 'official' way (only used by Firefox) that doesn't even position the cursor correctly
        // VSC keeps telling me the method doesn't exist
        let pos = document.caretPositionFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        let range = document.createRange();

        range.setStart(pos.offsetNode, pos.offsetX);
        range.collapse(true);

        return range;
    } else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
        // The 'deprecated WebKit-proprietary fallback method' (used by every mf browser out there)
        return document.caretRangeFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }
}

function selectRange(range) {
    const sel = window.getSelection();

    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

#editable {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

#editable[contenteditable="false"] {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#editable[contenteditable="false"]::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="false" onblur="this.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);">Double click to edit this text</div>
<ul>
  <li>Caret is placed where clicked, not at the start</li>
  <li>Double clicked word is not highlighted</li>
  <li>Text can not be interacted with if the element isn't focused</li>
</ul>
```

It is long, complicated, but it works. The API for this is completely messed up in my opinion. I hope this can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to allow pointer events before the double-click, hiding the ability with the cursor, there's no need for anything complicated, just prevent the double-click action when adding contenteditable while making sure it's in focus, and the original single click will fall through.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (event.detail > 1) { // double-clicked
    const e = event.target;
    if (e.id === "content" && !['true', 'plaintext-only'].includes(e.contentEditable)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      e.style.cursor = 'auto';
      e.contentEditable = true;
      e.focus();
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#content {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Edit this text</div>
```